# Example of Python + Redland for RDF Storage and Retrieval

Tags: python, rdf, redland

Would someone please point to an example of using Python to store RDF data using Redland / RDF, and later to retrieve the data.

I see there is a lot of Redland documentation out there, and I'm sure it's excellent, but I'm quite new to RDF and don't have a strong grasp of C, so I can't quite make my way through it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [redland-bindings](https://github.com/dajobe/redland-bindings) Github project has [a Python example](https://github.com/dajobe/redland-bindings/blob/master/python/example.py) which shows storage of statements into an RDF store and then querying for them.

Comment: A thousand blessings upon you, my friend.